# Is there a difference between `command rspec` and `rspec`?

Tags: shell-script, ruby

I want to call `bundle exec rspec` if `Gemfile` exists in current directory, and if it doesn't exists, call `rspec` itself. So I wrote like this.

```
function rspec() {
    if [ -e 'Gemfile' ]; then
    echo 'call bundle exec rspec'
    bundle exec rspec
    else
    echo 'call rspec'
    command rspec
    fi
}
```

But when I run `rspec --init` where `Gemfile` doesn't exist, I get this error.

> /Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in
>   `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/ironsand/tmp/spec (LoadError)

Error indicate there is no spec directory, but `rspec --init` should create the directory by itself.

If `Gemfile` exists, `rspec` works fine.

I think this error occurs because of a difference that made by `command`.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `command` is not the problem here. The problem is that you're passing `--init` to your function, but your function is not passing this parameter to the real `rspec`. So your function isn't really calling `rspec --init` like you expect, but only `rspec`, and therefore it dies with an error.

Comment: Try to change `command rspec` to `command rspec "$@"`.